# Gmail is asking for a phone number verification to sign up. I don't have a phone or anyone else's number to give. What do I do?

Tags: gmail

None of my friends would let me, even if I asked them. And I sure can't ask my parents. Gmail won't create the account without a phone number, and I don't have access to a payphone, much less the number to one. It's driving me insane. Yahoo won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Google needs to know if you're real or not, ask someone you know his cellphone for some seconds...

That's on the Google guidelines (http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=114129)

> Signing up without a phone
>
> If you don't have a phone, you can use a friend's number to request
>   the code via text message or voice call. You don't have to worry about
>   your friend's number being attached to your account. Google won't use
>   this number for anything else besides account verification.

Comment: Link is dead.  Here in the future, they will force you to use that same number to verify if they say they need to verify.

Comment: The comment has been posted 4 years ago when the 2 step verification was at its beginning. I'll update the answer soon.